# Реализация слайд шоу на android

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать слайд шоу на android, задавая время между слайдами, используя библиотеку http://marvinlabs.github.io/android-slideshow-widget/ Загрузку слайдов нужно выполнять из внутренней памяти телефона? Готовый слайд должен быть в формате .mp4?

Comment: Уточните, что вы имеете в виду под слайд-шоу. Скорее всего вам нужен просто `ViewPager`

Comment: нужно, чтобы была возможность создавать ролик слайд шоу с выбранным интервалом времени как между слайдами, так и всего шоу. Фото нужно брать из SD - карты или внутреннего устройства?

Answer (score 1):

Первый же запрос в гугль "android slideshow library", [вот ссылка](http://marvinlabs.github.io/android-slideshow-widget/) на либу, просто добавьте её в проект и прочитайте READMI и не надо ничего думать самому и плов готов.

Вот это

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.marvinlabs:android-slideshow-widget-picasso-plugin:0.4.+@aar'
}
```

Добавьте в ваш Gradle.build

И обязательно пересинхронизируйте Gradle, чтобы тот подкачал либу, иначе будет подсвечено красны в коде, как ошибка, при использовании либы

Comment: Фото понятно как загружать, а что касается времени между слайдами?

Comment: Я не знаю, это не моя либа, читайте READMI, если не указано, значит скорее всего изменить нельзя, если вас это не устраивает, то кто вам мешает скачать исходники и порыться и самому допилить такой функционал?

Comment: я больше чем уверен, что данное время задаётся автором, а вы тупо можете добавить метод, который будет изменять это время, всего 1 строчка кода для метода, который бы изменял поле, отвечающее за это время.